# SharePoint Server 2013 Search Benchmarking

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search

What are the possible benchmarks that can give an idea about search performance in SharePoint Server 2013 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how SP Search compares to other products or what you should measure to create baseline?

Comment: Have look on those: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff599526(v=office.14).aspx They are about the SP2010 but FAST engine hasn't changed much since 2010 so most of it should be still applicable.

Comment: Hi Marek, I'm looking for how to benchmark SP 2013 Search performance, what are the most common used KPI's ? Such as Crawl rate, document indexing rate, etc ... and eventually how to measure them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So with Search in my opinion the Crawl Rate and Query Time are most important, as they affect the experience. The Test for 2010 can give you indication what to expect. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff599526(v=office.14).aspx . The scaling article will give you guidance which resources are most important. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn727118.aspx. Search is IOPS hungry and the faster disk you can give it the better. I have some fantastic experience with ExtremeIO (SSD storage). The values for crawl rate and queries you can find in the search report in search service administration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your first link is corrupted. Please update it.

Comment: thx. updated the link.

Answer (score 1):

You should download and test the SharePoint SRx Search Health Reports. These reports provide tons of deep metrics on the search service application. Pay attention to Crawler Health and Index Reports with:

`$xSSA | Get-SRxIndexReports -DiskReport`

[Announcing the Search Health Reports SRx for SharePoint Search Diagnostics](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint_strategery/2016/02/01/announcing-the-search-health-reports-srx-for-sharepoint-search-diagnostics/) and [Create a Search Service Status Dashboard](https://searchexplained.com/create-a-search-service-status-dashboard/)